# No compatible source was found for this video in android using Videojs

Tags: flash, video.js, rtmp

I am using a sample code to setup rtmp video streaming in browser using Videojs.
This seem to work fine in desktop pc but same does not in Android browser.

I get the Error: No compatible source was found for this video

The code i am using is:

```html
<head>
  <link href="http://vjs.zencdn.net/5.7.1/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- If you'd like to support IE8 -->
  <script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/ie8/1.1.2/videojs-ie8.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <video id="my-video" class="video-js" controls preload="auto" width="640" height="264"
  poster="MY_VIDEO_POSTER.jpg" data-setup="{}">
    <source src="link to rtmp videp" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="MY_VIDEO.webm" type='video/webm'>
    <p class="vjs-no-js">
      To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that
      <a href="http://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank">supports HTML5 video</a>
    </p>
  </video>

  <script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/5.7.1/video.js"></script>
</body>
```

I have copied code  from : http://videojs.com/getting-started/

Is it because Mobile browser does not support flash and because i am using RTMP?

Comment: Where is your video?

Comment: RTMP isn't playable on Android of course but webm should play. You need to include the source URLs in your example for anyone to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I dont know if the video tag for Android browser can decode RTMP links. RTSP has been said to work as **[discussed in this link](https://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/questions/5496622-streaming-on-android)**

Answer (score 0):

This is to put the web page on the server and can’t open it directly. However, the one opened directly with idea should also be put on the server. However, you should not be able to double-click the HTML file to open it. I haven’t tried. After that, I found that the flash in the browser was in “query” status

And then try to change this to “allowed state”, which is actually OK..

for more information [rtmp server](https://developpaper.com/realization-of-rtmp-live-streaming-by-html5/)